# Astronomy online degrees

Tags: radio-astronomy, data-analysis, n-body-simulations, seti

I have a masters degree in computer science and statistics but would like to advance my knowledge in astronomy, ideally in getting some kind of online degree.

Does anybody have experience, suggestions or recommendation where I can do what without having to be physically present at a university?

Also, I would like to get view on what specific topics in astronomy it would make sense to focus if my skills are mainly in computer science and data analysis?

Comment: The Open University has some popular online courses in astronomy (http://www.open.ac.uk/courses/find/astronomy-and-planetary-science), they can be taken on their own or as part of a full degree course.

Comment: Online degrees aren't worth the paper they're not printed on

Comment: @Carl Witthoft That's not a very constructive comment

Comment: But it's true.  Whatever you do, don't pay for such services.

Comment: You may be right, but the only thing I'm interested is learning more about astronomy on a level so I can do meaningful research. Money doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

Try https://www.coursera.org/courses?query=astronomy

Online courses from several universities. Some are on a schedule with online lectures, etc. Others you can just do yourself at any time.

Also there are extensive libraries on YouTube, for instance from this guy Michel van Biezen.
http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLX2gX-ftPVXWddG6sGq6H-3cN0IQzfQmG

That link goes to the first of his playlists about astronomy. His astronomy section has about 20 parts!